# Combine String Literals and interpolation in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, string, interpolation, string-literals

I have a piece of templated HTML string and I want to replace particular parts of it with real values. As you can see in the picture, I've combined the good old C# string literals and the new cool C# 6.0 string interpolation, but it's not working.

The source of problem are the double quotes for string indexers. I tried to escape the " characters with '\' and it didn't work, either.

In a single line string (without '@'), there is no problem with double quotes for string indexers.

Does anymore have a solution for this? Thanks.

[image]

UPDATE: Here is the code:

```
    string hubspotEmbedCode =
$@"<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset='utf-8' type='text/javascript' src='//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset='utf-8' type='text/javascript' src='//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js'></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({{
    sfdcCampaignId: '{(Model.MacroParameters["CampainId"])}',
    portalId: '{(Model.MacroParameters["PortalId"])}',
    formId: '{Model.MacroParameters["FormId"]}'
  }});
</script>";
```

Comment: could you paste your code as part of the question please?

Comment: Add parentheses around the expression - `{(Model.MacroParameters["CampainId"].ToString())}`

Comment: Also note that `Campaign` is misspelled, and `ToString()` may not be necessary (it will be called by the `String.Format` that the compiler generates..

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this.  Once inside of the brackets `{}` for the interpolated string I am able to have literal strings for indexers.  It would help if we could copy and paste the string though.

Comment: Thank you all. 
@D Stanley, I tried to wrap it with ( ), but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh shoot! I tried it in a console app and it's fine! My code is in a .cshtml view file, and it's not working there!